# reactjs typescript event this undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got the following component written in typescript. (type definitions from definitelytyped.org). I got the onWheel event bound to a function. But when ever it is fired `this` is undefined, so how am I supposed to access the referenced element `this.div` and if I would want/need to change the state how should do that?

```
import React = require('react');

interface fooProps {
    src: string;
}

class foo extends React.Component<fooProps, {}>
{
    private div: HTMLDivElement;

    public onWheel(e: React.WheelEvent): void {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        //Do stuff with the div, but 'this' is undefined!!
        this.div;
    }
    public render(): JSX.Element {
                return (
            <div ref={(ref) => this.div = ref} onWheel= { this.onWheel} >
                <img src={ this.props.src } />
                </div >)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know about Typescript, but I'm guessing it's the same thing as when creating components using the similar ES2015 syntax which will need a constructor, and function binding to make a reference to this.onWheel work.

So in ES2015,

```
class foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Magic happens here:
    this.onWheel = this.onWheel.bind(this)
    // Now each instance of foo can use this.onWheel
  }

  onWheel () {
    ....
  }

  render (){
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a preferred way of binding event handlers in React components to the answer by Qwertiy. If you do the binding inside the constructor like in the snippet above, that means you only create a copy of the function once whereas if you do it inside of the `render` method the function will get re-created every time React re-renders the component. Worth bearing it in mind when performance is a major consideration.

Comment: But then how is the event bound? I still got to put onWheel={this.onWheel} in the render method right?

Comment: Just do it the way you already do. It should work fine. My code example didn't have `onWheel(e: React.WheelEvent)`, because the point was what's going on in the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution if you don't want to bind each function in the constructor is to use lambdas:

```
class foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // The lambda creates a lexical scope so it's autobound
  onWheel = () => {
    ....
  }

  render () {
    ....
  }
}
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> onWheel= { this.onWheel}
> ```

```
onWheel={this.onWheel.bind(this)}
```

Comment: You can also write it in lambda form `onWheel={e => this.onWheel(e)}` it will call the appropriate method using closures

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing would be converting it into an arrow function which binds automatically:

```
 public onWheel = (e: React.WheelEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //Do stuff with the div, and yes you can work with 'this' in this function
    this.div;
}
```